# Count total +1's and Shares of a particular post Google plus(Google+)

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services

I am working on android application in which I require following functionality:

1.I post something from my application to google plus and **google plus should return me a post id.**

2.With Post id I want to find out **number of likes(+1) or share happened for my post**.

I have used sample project of Google Plus application provided in android sdk. and also read this guide https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/

But unable to find some solution.This can be easily achieved in case of FaceBook sdk and Twitter.

So **Is google plus provide something so that i can find out count of likes or shares for a perticular post using post id?**

Comment: The [activities.get](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/get) API method lists the number of replies, plusoners, and resharers. I'm not sure about getting the activityId initially on Android though.